# The Parameter List its jumping the First ID of Table on SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I Need get all values of parameter param_IDFICHA if it exist and fills all parameter lists with yours respective values. More its jumping first ID and its getting starting of second ID.

Ex:

If I have on Data SQL

```
Jhon 3 2

Crazy 1 2

Egg 4 1
```

The list parameter its listing only

```
Crazy 1 2

Egg 4 1
```

Code

```
public void Search_IDFicha(int param_IDFICHA, List<string> list_peixe, List<string> list_quant, List<string> list_peso)
    {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        vsql = "SELECT [ID_FICHA], [RGP], [PEIXE], [PESO], [QUANTIDADE], [DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE ID_FICHA = @ID_FICHA";
        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_FICHA", param_IDFICHA));

                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objReader.Read())
                {
                    valor.retorna_IdFIcha = objReader.GetInt32(0);

                    while (objReader.Read())
                    {
                        list_peixe.Add(objReader.GetString(2));
                        list_peso.Add(objReader.GetDouble(3).ToString());
                        list_quant.Add(objReader.GetInt32(4).ToString());
                    }

                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
        }

    }

   private void btn_Buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int param_idficha = Convert.ToInt32(txtb_idFicha.Text);

      _peixe_list.Clear();
       _quant_list.Clear();
       _peso_list.Clear();

       objSQL.Search_IDFicha(param_idficha,_peixe_list,_quant_list,_peso_list);

       int i = String.Compare(Convert.ToString(valor.retorna_IdFIcha), Convert.ToString(param_idficha));

       listBox1.DataSource = _peixe_list;

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing READ() twice. It should be called in the loop only.
Every time you call Read() method, it advances to the next record, which is why you are skipping first record.

```
public void Search_IDFicha(int param_IDFICHA, List<string> list_peixe, List<string> list_quant, List<string> list_peso)
    {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        vsql = "SELECT [ID_FICHA], [RGP], [PEIXE], [PESO], [QUANTIDADE], [DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE ID_FICHA = @ID_FICHA";
        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_FICHA", param_IDFICHA));

                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (objReader.Read())
                {
                    valor.retorna_IdFIcha = objReader.GetInt32(0);
                    list_peixe.Add(objReader.GetString(2));
                    list_peso.Add(objReader.GetDouble(3).ToString());
                    list_quant.Add(objReader.GetInt32(4).ToString());
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
        }

    }
```